# Raspberry PI Fuse exec format error

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, raspbian

After installing raspbian on my RaspBerry(model B), I cannot use fuse.
when I type `modprobe fuse`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Exec format error
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11-rpi-aufs #1 PREEMPT Sun May 26 18:32:32 CEST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Output of "modinfo fuse"

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.6.11-rpi-aufs/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
alias:          devname:fuse
alias:          char-major-10-229
alias:          fs-fuseblk
alias:          fs-fuse
license:        GPL
description:    Filesystem in Userspace
author:         Miklos Szeredi <miklos@szeredi.hu>
alias:          fs-fusectl
srcversion:     3E6EF89EEDFC3FFA016E7DA
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.18.11+ preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv6 
parm:           max_user_bgreq:Global limit for the maximum number of backgrounded requests an unprivileged user can set (uint)
parm:           max_user_congthresh:Global limit for the maximum congestion threshold an unprivileged user can set (uint)
```

Output of dmsg:

```
[   17.419311] snd: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[   23.451219] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   23.524241] EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
[   23.529655] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[   28.111719] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1
[   30.229454] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor ondemand
[   30.229488] bcm2835-cpufreq: switching to governor ondemand
[  389.540083] fuse: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1160.682514] fuse: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1386.760093] cuse: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1438.489749] cuse: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 2960.516582] fuse: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 3281.683973] fuse: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Output of: ls -l /lib/modules/*/modules.dep

    `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109852 Jun 26  2014 /lib/modules/3.12.23-rpi-aufs/modules.dep
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127504 Apr 27 14:40 /lib/modules/3.18.11+/modules.dep
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128059 Apr 27 14:40 /lib/modules/3.18.11-v7+/modules.dep
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   6689 Mär 10  2013 /lib/modules/3.4.24-a10-aufs+/modules.dep
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  97718 Mai 15 19:31 /lib/modules/3.6.11-rpi-aufs/modules.dep`

Comment: You have kernel modules that don't match your running kernel. What is the output of `ls -l /lib/modules/*/modules.dep` ? Does rebooting help (it might if you've upgraded your kernel since the last reboot)?

Comment: No, rebooting does not work :-( And there is no such folder modules.deb, all i can get is the following: sudo ls -l /lib/modules/*/ drwxrwxr-x 10 root root   4096 Jän  1  1970 kernel
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 316884 Mai 15 19:31 modules.alias
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 333102 Mai 15 19:31 modules.alias.bin
...

Comment: You don't have a `modules.dep`? (Not `modules.deb`. Copy-paste!) What kernel packages do you have installed? `dpkg -l 'linux-image-*'`

Comment: sorry, i hav entered .deb :-( Here is the output: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109852 Jun 26  2014 /lib/modules/3.12.23-rpi-aufs/modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127504 Apr 27 14:40 /lib/modules/3.18.11+/modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128059 Apr 27 14:40 /lib/modules/3.18.11-v7+/modules.dep
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   6689 Mär 10  2013 /lib/modules/3.4.24-a10-aufs+/modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  97718 Mai 15 19:31 /lib/modules/3.6.11-rpi-aufs/modules.dep

Comment: Please do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, *reboot* and provide the output of `uname -a && modinfo fuse`.

Comment: It seems that your running kernel and your installed modules are inconsistent. Did you compile your own kernel or install a kernel that didn't come from Raspbian? Try doing `apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-3.6.11-rpi-aufs`, then reboot.

Comment: No, this is nearly a fresh install. I only recompiled fuse, but that was after the original version didn't work. The package linux-image-3.6.11-rpi-aufs does not exist. I have added the output of "modinfo fuse" above.